# Angular 2 how to call markAsDirty() on control inside ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular

I have a Date of birth custom control, with 3 inner inputs.
I only want the parent control to be marked as dirty, when all 3 inputs are dirty.

I need to access the control of the NgModel from within the Custom value accessor, How can I achieve this? The code isn't neccessary, but is below:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[validateDateOfBirth][formControlName],[validateDateOfBirth][formControl],[validateDateOfBirth][ngModel]',
  providers: [
  { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateOfBirthValidator), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class DateOfBirthValidator implements Validator {
  constructor(@Attribute('validateDateOfBirth') public validateDateOfBirth: string) {

  }
  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    let v: DateOfBirthVm  = c.value;
    let valid = false;
    if(v && v.month && v.year) {
      return null;
    }
    return {
      validateDateOfBirth: false
    }
  }
}
```

```ts
<date-of-birth
  validateDateOfBirth
  ngDefaultControl
  [(ngModel)]="model.dateOfBirth"
  #dateOfBirth="ngModel"
  name="dateOfBirth"></date-of-birth>
```

```ts
export class DateOfBirth implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() name: string;

  private _viewModel: DateOfBirthVm = new DateOfBirthVm();

  private _yearOptions: Array<number> = [];
  private _monthInputValue: string = '';
  private _monthControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  private _yearInputValue: string = '';
  private _yearControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  constructor(private _appSettings: AppSettings) {
    this._monthControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
      this._viewModel.month = value;
    });
    this._yearControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
      this._viewModel.year = value;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for(let i=(this._appSettings.currentYear-18); i>1909; i--) {
      this._yearOptions.push(i);
    }
  }

  //Interface specific stuff.
  //To notify external component's that the model has changed, we must call our
  //registeredOnChange handler. (e.g _onChanged()). Simply calling it, informs other components.
  registerOnChange(fn: any) { this._onChanged = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this._onTouched = fn; }
  private _onChanged = (value) => { };
  private _onTouched = () => { };
  //write value is called when an external component writes to our model.
  //e.g if another component with ([ngModel])="myAutoCompleteValue", calls myAutoCompleteValue = '';
  writeValue(vm: DateOfBirthVm) {
    if(!vm) {
      this._viewModel.month = '';
      this._viewModel.year = '';
    } else {
      this._viewModel = vm;
      this._monthInputValue = vm.month;
      this._yearInputValue = vm.year;
      this._onChanged(vm);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "access the control of the NgModel". Isn't that `DateOfBirth` or do you want to call it on the parent component where `<date-of-birth>` is used?

Comment: "The code isn't neccessary, but is below:" The code is absolutely necessary. The question wouldn't make much sense without it. It's hard enough to understand with the code ;-)

Comment: My mistake! Basically the issue is, validateDateOfBirth (please see edit) displays a validation messages when dateOfBirth is dirty. But dateOfBirth is being made dirty when just one of the child fields are touched, rather than when all 3, so my validation message is displayed prematurely. Perhaps my knowledge of this situation isn't good enough to find an elegant solution, could you please advise? Thanks!

Comment: Waht is `validateDateOfBirth`?

Comment: It's a custom validator, have added in edit.

Comment: Just don't call `_onChanged()` or `_onTouched()` when not all are changed yet.

Comment: Brilliant thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't call `_onChanged()` or `_onTouched()` when not all are changed yet.